Why were the Sadducees convinced by Jesus' argument about the resurrection?
Unless I'm missing some Biblical or historical context, Jesus' argument supporting the resurrection seems to hinge on a grammatical choice.
Jesus' words:

'But about the resurrection of the dead—have you not read what God said to you, ‘I am the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob’ ? He is not the God of the dead but of the living.” Matthew 22:31-32
https://www.bible.com/bible/111/MAT.22.31-32

The quoted scripture:

'Then he said, “I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob.” At this, Moses hid his face, because he was afraid to look at God. ' Exodus 3:6 https://www.bible.com/bible/111/EXO.3.6

Is the entire argument here the choice of "am" instead of "was"? If so, why was that so convincing to the Sadducees?
For example, let's say my father had a best friend. My father then dies, and I meet his best friend for the first time. To modern ears, saying, "I am a friend of your father.", even though he has died, wouldn't cause me to think my father was still alive.
It's awkward phrasing, sure, but if I'm a Sadducee I can't imagine not pushing back on this. So is there more to it? Was the Hebrew here much less ambiguous?

While this is an admittedly over simplification, it can generally be said that Biblical Hebrew omits the present tense of the verb “to be” in subject complement constructions. In linguistics, this phenomenon where the verb is omitted is called a zero copula. Exodus 3:6 is an example of such a construction; the verb “am” is in parentheses because it is not present in the Hebrew:
אָנֹכִי אֱלֹהֵי אָבִיךָ 
I (am) the God of thy father

Subject complements can be predicate adjectives, predicate nouns, or predicate pronouns. The subject complement in Ex 33:6 is a predicate noun (God). In order to determine the function in context, I looked at whether the referent of “God” is unique or non-unique, concluding that it is unique. If so, then the predicate identifies rather than describes the subject. Thus, God is not describing Himself as the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, as though there are other gods for other people. Rather, He is identifying Himself by the title “the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob” (cf. Ex 3:15).
Commentary of Keil & Delitzsch on Exodus 3:6

Jehovah then made Himself known to Moses as the God of his fathers,
Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, reminding him through that name of the
promises made to the patriarchs, which He was about to fulfill to
their seed, the children of Israel.

Given the above discussion, Jesus’ argument in Mt 22:32b is astonishing in its simplicity. His point is that God would not refer to Himself in such terms, as “the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob,” if those individuals were not still living. While not conclusive on its own, the present tense of εἰμί (Strong’s G1510 meaning I exist, I am) in Mt 22:32 supports this interpretation.

@Corey (edited to include ref.) According to this paper, context determines the tense of the zero copula. Given the subject and context of Ex 3:6, the statement can be understood as a-temporal or perhaps even eternal. If so, the clause can be translated as I was, I am, and I will be…

While I'm still not completely satisfied, I think this is the best answer.

For my part, I appreciate how your question challenges the way that Mt 22:32 is usually interpreted. What confirmed the above interpretation for me is the way Jesus carefully quoted Ex 3:6, preserving the original wording. If he had paraphrased it in any way, I would not be confident that we are looking at a title and not just a description of God.

The OP asks specifically about the Hebrew of Ex 3:6 and the tense of the verb that God uses in talking to Moses.  We observe several things about that quotation:

Hebrew verbs do not have tense and so the question of whether a Hebrew verb is past present of future is moot because it has no meaning.
No explicit verb exists in the Hebrew - it literally reads: "I the God of your father, the God of Abraham, ..."
The closest we get is its translation by the LXX (about 250 BC) into Greek which the NT quotes which says, Ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ θεὸς τοῦ πατρός σου, θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ ... = "I am the God of your father, God of Abraham, ... "  This verb is in the simple present tense.

The NT text of Jesus statement is the same:

Ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰσαὰκ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰακώβ; οὐκ ἔστιν ὁ
θεὸς νεκρῶν ἀλλὰ ζώντων. = I am the God of Abraham and the God of
Isaak and the God Jacob.  He is not the God of dead but living.


This adds important context to the question, so I upvoted, but it still doesn't answer the question. This comment puts it nicely. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/98717/why-were-the-sadducees-convinced-by-jesus-argument-about-the-resurrection/98729#comment202515_98724

This doesn't answer the question why was that so convincing to the Sadducees?, it just gives a somewhat accurate background on the relevant Hebrew grammar

@AviAvraham - It is convincing precisely because God is!  And God is the God of the living and not the dead; therefore the dead will be raised.

Re: "Hebrew verbs do not have tense..." https://alhatorah.org/Grammar:Tenses_in_Tanakh

The gospel account in Luke chapter 20 from verse 27 to the end gives Jesus' exact words to the Sadducees. This is the text that needs to be looked at hermeneutically, and not the Exodus 3:6 one, which will become clear when the particular verse is copied below:

"Now, that the dead are raised, even Moses shewed at the bush, when he
calleth the Lord the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God
of Jacob. For he is not a God of the dead, but of the living: for all
live unto him." Luke 20:37-38 K.J.V.

Jesus quoted from Exodus 3:6, showing God to be the originator of those words. (See Exodus 6:3). Jesus confirmed the truth of Moses' words, quoting him, and agreeing, plus adding a bit more: that they live unto God. This shows why the Sadducees were silenced.
Note that the account does not say the Sadducees were convinced by Jesus' argument! They were left without a leg to stand on, and Jesus' rebuttal of their wrong theology contributed to the Scribes and the Pharisees giving up on trying to trap Jesus with questions that would enable them to hand him over to the Roman authorities (Luke 20:20).
Note also, that the Scribes agreed with Jesus' argument, for the Scribes believed in the resurrection of the dead. The Sadducees did not (hence their trick question on marriage in the resurrection). Jesus' proof from the lips of Moses delighted them, for (on that point) they agreed with Jesus. But the Sadducees never said Jesus had convinced them. They just had to zip it, and stop trying to trip him up with their malintentioned questions.
As for what Moses said, it was a point further to the way God had identified himself to him as having the name, "I AM". Moses quoted God as saying to him at the bush,

"Thou shalt say unto the children of Israel, The Lord God of your
fathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob,
hath sent me unto you; this is my name for ever..." Exodus 3:14-16
K.J.V.

Given the length of time those three forefathers of the nation of Israel had lived, and how bone-dead all of them were by then, God was saying he was still their God. Impossible, unless those three were alive in another way. Then, when Jesus agreed, quoting all of that, he showed that Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob remained alive thousands of years on, with God still being their God. And, to top it all, Jesus took the name of "I AM" to himself (John 8:58). No wonder those who hated Jesus (including the Scribes), wanting to silence him and having failed to do so with their words, resorted to trying to stone him to death, and when that failed, got him handed over to the Roman authorities.
The grammatical choice of words in Exodus 3 and Luke 20 is deliberate in both instances. The present tense teaches massively important truths as to the name of God and how that bears on God still being the God of those who died in faith, but who have passed over from death to life.

"The grammatical choice of words in Exodus 3 and Luke 20 is deliberate in both instances."
My question remains unanswered then. Unless you're saying there is no more too it, and the grammar alone was sufficient to quiet the Sadducees?

@Corey   The Scribes, the Pharisees and the Sadducees all knew the theology behind those strange uses of present tense. Only the Sadducees disagreed with that theology but the way Jesus answered them silenced them. On the Day of Resurrection their disagreement with the words of God, Moses and Christ will condemn them. Their silence will be turned into wailing.

but why did it silence them? Why not respond to Jesus with: "But that doesn't prove a resurrection. It only proves it's the same God?"

@Corey  The Sadducees were thinking according to 1st century understanding, which included knowing all about the theology of what God & Moses said re. the dead saints. It's just no use trying to apply Western, 21st century thinking to the matter. We have to try to put ourselves into the mind-set of those people. The Bible records all we need to know to grasp what God would have us understand. And what is left unsaid must be left by us until that awesome day "when everything hidden will be revealed."

God calls things that are not as though they were.  Abraham Issac and Jacob are dead and unconscious but they will be raised immortal at the first resurrection, so from God's viewpoint they are "living" even though dead because their resurrection is as certain as if they were still living.  Figuratively speaking they never died in the mind of God and are figuratively still living.  The unsaved dead however are dead figuratively and literally and await a resurrection to judgment but not necessarily damnation.

"grammar alone was sufficient" Language is grammar; what else do you want to be sufficient? The difference between past and present is the difference between "he is alive" and "he was alive". A mere point of grammar, but describing very different realities.

The Sadducees do not believe in a future resurrection of the dead, so they pose a question that they think Jesus will not be able to answer without making the belief in resurrection look silly.
But Jesus responds with two points:

When resurrected, people will be immortal spirits, and lacking physical bodies, they would not be concerned with the concept of marriage and sexual relations.
Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob are all dead and buried, yet God still claims to be their God.

The first one nicely answers their question, causing their trap to fail.
The second one points out that by saying "I am" rather than "I was" God indicates that they still exist and will eventually live again.
So, not only do they fail in presenting Jesus with a question he wouldn't be able to answer, they themselves are presented with a situation that they didn't have an answer for.
As verse 34 says "he had put the Sadducees to silence".

Understood, and maybe I'm failing to ask my question properly. Why did that put the Sadducees to silence? If someone made that argument to me, I would simply say "God saying IS instead of WAS doesn't necessarily point to a resurrection. 'I am the God of your fathers', to modern ears, could be easily be swapped to 'I was the God of your fathers' with little semantic difference."
The Sadducees being silenced, though, would suggest the present tense held a strong semantic meaning for them. Why?

I wonder the same thing, as it could be like saying (in English at least/of course), "I am the God that Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob believed in."
God is... so it makes sense that He would use present tense even for past-tense people.

Thanks, @TheChaz2.0! That correctly summarizes my point.
